# SonarLint in PhpStorm Not Highlighting Code Conventions Like SonarCloud

Tags: github, phpstorm, sonarcloud

I'm using the SonarLint extension for PhpStorm and have successfully connected it to my organization on SonarCloud. However, I've noticed that it's not alerting on code conventions in the same way as SonarCloud does.

For instance, when SonarCloud runs on GitHub pipelines, it picks up "code smells" like:

```
1. Rename this field "$tax_value" to match the regular expression ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$.

2. Split this 127 characters long line (which is greater than 120 authorized).
```

However, these same "code smells" aren't being flagged in PhpStorm with SonarLint. Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? Is there any additional configuration that I need to adjust in PhpStorm to align them with SonarCloud's behavior?

I appreciate any help.